# Как проверить тип установленной модели в QTableView для организации ветвления

Tags: qt5

Есть представление `QTableView`, оно отображает модель `QSqlTableModel`. Организован поиск через `QSortFilterProxyModel`, и результаты поиска помещаются в тот-же `QTableView`. Для редактирования записей создана форма `QDataWidgetMapper`.

Необходимо проверить, какая сейчас модель активна в `QTableView`, и на основании этого вызвать правильную привязку `QDataWidgetMapper`.

Код методы вызова формы:

```
void MyForm::setMyModel(MySqlTableModel *myModel)
{
    this->initForm(myModel);
    this->init();
}

void MyForm::setMyProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel *proxy)
{
    this->initForm(proxy);
    this->init();
}
```

А тут должна быть правильная проверка:

```
void MainWindow::on_tableViewUi_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    this->myEditForm = new MyForm();
    this->myEditForm->setParent(this, Qt::Window);
    this->myEditForm->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);

    qDebug() << "Я ТУТ" << this->ui->tableViewUi->selectionModel()->model();
//возвращает модель
    if(this->ui->tableViewUi->selectionModel()->model() == QSqlTableModel//не работает) 
//а вот как проверить и выполнить if???
    {
        this->myEditForm->setMyModel(this->mySqlTableModel);
    }
    if(this->ui->tableViewUi->selectionModel()->model() == QSortFilterProxyModel) //не работает...
    {
        this->myEditForm->setMyProxyModel(this->sortModel);
    }
    this->myEditForm->getMyMapper()->setCurrentModelIndex(index);
    this->myEditForm->show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В Qt все модели являются наследниками `QAbstractItemModel`, которая в свою очередь наследуется от `QObject`. Соответственно становится возможной проверка типа объекта посредством метода `QObject::inherits()`:

```
QAbstractItemModel *model = this->ui->tableViewUi->selectionModel()->model();
if(model->inherits("QSqlTableModel") == true) { ... }
else if(model->inherits("QSortFilterProxyModel") == true) { ... }
```

Comment: вариант. Попробую сейчас

Answer (score 0):

Задача решена. Весь вывод из всех методов осуществить через QSortFilterProxyModel и проверки становятся не нужны.